# put an element always on bottom while sorting

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

I have a list of items (div, for instance) with an integer attribute that helps me sorting that list (ascending and descending); I want some items always at the bottom not matter the sort criteria, is there a way to put a value on this integer attribute to get this (separately, I put -9999 while desc order, and 999999 in asc order, but I need only one value).

Comment: Remove it from the array, sort the array, add it back to the array.

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
myArray = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'itemLast', 'item4']; 

//SORT array here

// remove the item you want by name
myArray.splice(myArray.indexOf('itemLast'),1);

// push it again
myArray.push('itemLast');
```